# How to compare values in dataframe to values from another rows using Python and Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

So, I have a dataframe with number of columns, basically the following structure:

```
Date    Low     High     Close   Position    Stop_loss     Take_profit     Return
21.03   0.234   0.235    0.234   Long        0.23          0.238           0,01709401709
22.03   0.232   0.237    0.235
23.04   0.235   0.239    0.238
```

If `position == 'Long'` it must take `Stop_loss` and `Take_profit` and compare it to `low` and `high` columns of the next row. If value in `Take profit` <= value in `high` of the next row, and value in `Stop_loss` < value in `low` of the next row, that means take profit got hit and we fill the `Return` with `(Take_profit'/'Close')-1`. The opposite scenario for stop loss. **In case neither stop loss nor take profit got hit, it must go next row and so on until one of targets getting hit.** This part I am particularly struggling with. How to build the function that will go through the values of columns (`low` and `high`), compare them to `Take_profit` and `Stop_loss` and write result in return in case one of targets got hit?

Code that doesn't work since idk how to compare values from one row to values in a following rows (I used .shift(1) method but it doesn't work and anyway it would check only to next row instead of go through all the following rows until find the needed value):

```
def func(row):

  if 'Long' in row['Position']:
      if (row['Take_profit'] <= row['high'].shift(1)) & (row['Stop_loss'] < row['Low'].shift(1)):
          return ((row['Take_profit']/row['Close'])-1)
      elif (row['Stop_loss'] >= row['Low'].shift(1)) & (row['Take_profit'] > 
      row['High'].shift(1)):
          return ((row['Stop_loss']/row['Close'])-1)
  #this condition if hit both stop loss and take profit:
  else:
      return null 
df['Returns'] = df[df['Position'].isnull() == False].apply(func,axis =1)
```

Comment: Could you please edit your question to reflect exactly what you're asking? At the moment it's not very clear. If you could add any stack traces you're getting that would be helpful too.

Comment: I tried, hope it helps